# How to alternate redstone signal?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I want to create a circuit that when a button is pushed, one piston goes after a delay from another piston, but when the button is reset (i.e. when it is released), then the same piston retracts first and then the second piston retracts later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want an "ABBA circuit": When you turn the input on, first A turns on and then B, when you turn the input off, first B turns off and then A.

The Minecraft wiki lists multiple designs for those here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mechanics/Redstone/Miscellaneous_circuits#ABBA_circuit ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Mechanics/Redstone/Miscellaneous_circuits&oldid=1540094#ABBA_circuit))
More can be found online.

An easy example is this one, using the locking feature of repeaters:

[image]

Comment: can you please explain how does this work?

Comment: When you turn the input on, first A turns on, then 1 RS tick later B, then 1 RS tick later the repeater in front of A gets locked. When you turn the output off, first the redstone in front of the repeater in front of A turns off, but the repeater is still locked, so it stays on, then 1 RS tick later B turns off, then 1 RS tick later the locking repeater turns off, unlocking the repeater in front of A, which turns off A.